# phpMailer mailing list don't send

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm having problems sending emails with a mailing list, this is what i have now and no email are sended

```
 public function mailingList($email, $nome, $message){
    $destinatário = $this->getAllEmails();
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSendmail();
    $mail->setFrom('XXXX@xxxxx.xxx.xxx', 'Webmaster');
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Informação - XXXX';
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Body = "
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Mensagem da Administração</h1>
            <table>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td><strong>Mensagem:</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>$message</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>Equipa xxxxx.</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>Obrigado</p>
            </body>
            </html>";
    $mail->addAttachment('../img/logo_pek.gif');
    foreach ($destinatário as $dest) {
        $correio = $dest['email'];
        if($correio != ''){
            $mail->ClearAddresses();
            $mail->addAddress($correio, 'Informação - XXXX');
        }
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            return array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'O email não foi enviado...');
        }
        else{
            echo "Ok";
            return array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'O email foi enviado com sucesso...');
        }
    }
}
```

When i use var_dump($correio) in the loop i have all the emails, so i don't get why the email is not sended.
Any help?

Comment: Does sending a single email work? What's the error message?

Comment: I recommend looking at the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simple mistake in your loop:

```
foreach ($destinatário as $dest) {
    $correio = $dest['email'];
    if($correio != ''){
        $mail->ClearAddresses();
        $mail->addAddress($correio, 'Informação - XXXX');
    }
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        return array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'O email não foi enviado...');
    }
    else{
        echo "Ok";
        return array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'O email foi enviado com sucesso...');
    }
}
```

Either of those `return` staements will exit the function entirely, so it will never get beyond the first message, and you need to keep track of each sending result, not just one of them. I think you meant something like this:

```
$results = [];
foreach ($destinatário as $dest) {
    $correio = $dest['email'];
    if($correio != ''){
        $mail->ClearAddresses();
        $mail->addAddress($correio, 'Informação - XXXX');
    }
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        $results[$correio] = array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'O email não foi enviado...');
    }
    else{
        echo "Ok";
        $results[$correio] = array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'O email foi enviado com sucesso...');
    }
}
return $results;
```

Comment: Thanks, I can send now, but i have no response

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Check your mail server logs?

Comment: I mean now i have an array inside another one,i have this {"xxxx@xxxx.pt":{"status":"success","message":"O email foi enviado com sucesso..."}} , and the i should have this {"status":"success","message":"O email foi enviado com sucesso..."}  otherwise my response is undefined since i have this function $ret = $ebspma->mailingList($email, $nome, $message);
    echo json_encode($ret);

Comment: This is a design issue you need to decide for yourself. If you want to get the status of each message you send (because your function supports sending more than one), you need to return an array. If you need to process it before handing a status value back to your Ajax request, that's up to you too.

Comment: Thanks for your help Synchro. I will decide later..right now is working and it's all I need.

Answer (score -1):

Please use this example and test

```
<?php

require_once 'class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
// Now you only need to add the necessary stuff

// HTML body

$body = "</pre>
<div>";
$body .= " Hello
";
$body .= "<i>Your</i> personal photograph to this message.
";
$body .= "Sincerely,
";
$body .= "phpmailer test message ";
$body .= "</div>" ;

// And the absolute required configurations for sending HTML with attachement

$mail->AddAddress("sendemailto@mail.zz", "My-webpage Website");
$mail->Subject = "test for phpmailer-3";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->AddAttachment("phpmailer.gif");
if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "There was an error sending the message";
exit;
}
echo "Message was sent successfully";
```

Comment: This is based on an obsolete example and is missing vital parts.

Comment: @ Synchro this works for me and this example to try. Have you tested?

Comment: What I said still holds - I know because I wrote the original code you based it on. It also fails to answer the question.